# Is it possible to use WebGl/GLSL shaders on DOM elements?

Tags: dom, browser, glsl, webgl, shader

I'd like to use GLSL shaders to style a DOM element. I'm googling around and all I find are ways to include WebGl canvases into the DOM, and nothing about going the other way around.

Is there any way of passing the DOM as a texture to a shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because it would be a major security breach.

The most you can do is [use a library to render the dom to a canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas)

Comment: That's super unfortunate. Do you happen to know what I could read to understand the security issues? Is there any hope of shaders ever being added in some limited form? (from what I understand, 'CSS shaders' were abandoned?)

Comment: Yes, CSS shaders were abandoned. Too much work, not really useful, all kinds of issues. As for security the issue was you could read the contents the DOM elements by timing draw calls and making the shader take more time depending on its colors. By doing so you can read the contents of an iframe from another domain or read which links have been followed etc...